# Error submit to Google Play - Android Application

Tags: android, upload, google-play

I want to submit a games to Google Play without license key.
When I upload the APK files, I get the following error:

1. The server could not process your apk. Try again.
2. Google Play does not accept apks signed with the debug certificate. Create a new certificate that is valid for at least 50 years.

Why this error appear?
Can anyone help to solve it?
This application want to upload without license key.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot submit an app without signning it

Comment: no development issues you must sign your app

Comment: Create your own keystore and sign your APP.

Answer (score 2):

if you want to submit an app to googles app store **you must** signing your application with your own certificate(not with the debug certificate).

[Signing Your Applications](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

best regards,sammy

Answer (score 0):

Use the Export Signed Application Package... option in the right click menu in Eclipse. Then it'll walk you through the process.

Comment: Must export using Signed Application Package?

Comment: Yes. Google wont let you upload an unsigned application. The wizard will help you create a self-signed certificate you can use. Be sure not to lose it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a X.509 Certificate, Then use that certificate to Sign the APK, After that You also need to Zipalign the APK in order to upload to Appstore.

To Sign, You can follow this link It worked for me.

http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-sign-apk-zip-files/

After that you can follw this link to Zipalign

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/zipalign.html

I use the command "zipalign -v 4 "

(make sure you are in the \userandroid-sks\tools folder when you run the Zipalign command)